# mySQL update exiting value by variable amount

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I have a column in a table called stock_quantity. Each record has a specific number indicating the amount of stock currently in inventory. I am using node inquirer to prompt the user to input an amount to add to an existing stock_quantity record. I would like to update the specific record for stock_quantity without having to make a query to the database to get the existing stock-quantity. Is the possible or do i have to do the separate query to grab the specific existing quantity and then do the math before the update query?

If I use the following snippet I can update a record by a specific amount (e.g. 1):

```
connection.query("UPDATE product SET stock_quantity = stock_quantity + 1 
WHERE ?",
    [
      {
        item_id: itemID
      }
    ],
    function(err, result) {
      if(err) {
        console.log(err);
      }

      console.log("Stock Quantity of item " + itemID + " increased by " + 
      addQty + " units.");
    }
  );
```

However, if I try to update the record for stock_quantity by a variable amount I get an error.  I've tried the following:

```
var itemID = parseInt(answer.item_id);
var addQty = parseInt(answer.add_qty);

if(typeof addQty === "number") {

  connection.query("UPDATE product SET stock_quantity = stock_quantity + 
  addQTY WHERE ?",
    [
      {
        item_id: itemID
      }
    ],
    function(err, result) {
      if(err) {
        console.log(err);
      }

      console.log(result);

      console.log("Stock Quantity of item " + itemID + " increased by " + 
      addQty + " units.");
    }
  );
}
```

I've also tried this:

```
var itemID = parseInt(answer.item_id);
var addQty = parseInt(answer.add_qty);

if(typeof addQty === "number") {

  connection.query("UPDATE product SET ? WHERE ?",
    [
      {
        stock_quantity: stock_quantity + addQty
      },      
      {
        item_id: itemID
      }
    ],
    function(err, result) {
      if(err) {
        console.log(err);
      }

      console.log(result);

      console.log("Stock Quantity of item " + itemID + " increased by " + 
      addQty + " units.");
    }
  );
}
```

Finally, I tried this:

```
var itemID = parseInt(answer.item_id);
var addQty = parseInt(answer.add_qty);

if(typeof addQty === "number") {

  connection.query("UPDATE product SET stock_quantity = stock_quantity + ? 
  WHERE ?",
    [
      {
        addQty
      },
      {
        item_id: itemID
      }
    ],
    function(err, result) {
      if(err) {
        console.log(err);
      }

      console.log(result);

      console.log("Stock Quantity of item " + itemID + " increased by " + 
      addQty + " units.");
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: What is the error you get?

Answer (score 0):

You could concatenate the addition to the SQL string (even though I don't ever recommend that over parameters but here you control the value):

```
connection.query("UPDATE product SET stock_quantity = stock_quantity + " + addQTY + " WHERE ?",
    [
      {
        item_id: itemID
      }
    ],
    ...
```

or if you're always checking by `item_id` you can just parameterize the query:

```
connection.query("UPDATE product SET stock_quantity = stock_quantity + 
  ? WHERE item_id = ?",
    [ addQty, itemID ],
    ...
```